# How can I sum two queries in a new table without sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, subquery

I have two queries that get the sums of two different columns from two different tables. The issue I'm facing is that I want to avoid subqueries. Is there a way to get a sum of my results?

This is the 1st query:

```
SELECT TeamID, Count(HomeTeamID) AS LASTCOUNT1
FROM Games LEFT JOIN Teams as team1
ON Games.HomeTeamID = team1.TeamID
GROUP BY TeamID;
```

This is the 2nd query:

```
SELECT TeamID, Count(AwayTeamID) AS LASTCOUNT2
FROM Games LEFT JOIN Teams as team2
ON Games.HomeTeamID = team2.TeamID
GROUP BY TeamID;
```

Results:

```
|--TeamID--|--LASTCOUNT1--|
|    1     |       8      |
|    2     |       8      |
|    3     |       8      |
|    4     |       8      |
|    5     |       8      |
|    6     |       8      |
|    7     |       8      |
|    8     |       8      |

|--TeamID--|--LASTCOUNT2--|
|    1     |       8      |
|    2     |       8      |
|    3     |       8      |
|    4     |       8      |
|    5     |       8      |
|    6     |       8      |
|    7     |       8      |
|    8     |       8      |
```

How can I achieve desired results without a subquery with union?

```
|--TeamID--|--LASTCOUNT1--|--LASTCOUNT2--|--TOTALCOUNT--|
|    1     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    2     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    3     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    4     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    5     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    6     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    7     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
|    8     |       8      |       8      |      16      |
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you want to count the number of home and away games for each team.  In SQL Server, you can unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
SELECT v.TeamID, SUM(ishome) as num_homes, SUM(is_away) as num_aways
FROM Teams t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (HomeTeamID, 1, 0), (AwayTeamId, 0, 1)
     ) v(TeamId, ishome, isaway)
GROUP BY v.TeamID;
```

Comment: This is more elegent way of doing it. As far as I understand this converts the columns into rows performces the aggegation (which ignores the nulls?). 
The reason why I'm doing it because I also need a total games played, with addition to aways and homes. Changing to correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.TeamID,t1.LASTCOUNT,t2.LASTCOUNT,(t1.LASTCOUNT + t2.LASTCOUNT)
 as Sum from team2 t2  
join team1 t1 on t1.TeamID = t2.TeamID
```

[image]